# SQL Server : I need to combine multiple rows into one row with different column values

Tags: sql-server

I have a view

```
Order          Drink       Entree         Desert  
--------------------------------------------------
12             Null        Preparing      Null  
12             Ready       NULL           NULL   
12             NULL        NULL           Waiting
```

I want to convert it to:

```
Order          Drink       Entree         Desert  
---------------------------------------------------
12             Ready       Preparing      Waiting
```

Comment: I know this isn't the question you asked, but why on *Earth* do you have only one column with a non-`NULL` value on each row? Something is very wrong with the design that created this mess. Change the `INSERT`ing code as soon as possible.

Answer (score 5):

You can use an appropriate aggregation function. In this case, it seems like `MIN` or `MAX` will do the trick:

```
SELECT Order,
       MIN(Drink) Drink,
       MIN(Entree) Entree,
       MIN(Desert) Desert
FROM dbo.YourTable
GROUP BY Order;
```

Comment: That's what I would have done as well. If, of course, you might have more than one non-null row for the same order, then you'd have to figure out how to reconcile that.

Comment: @BradC exactly, but there's no enough information in the sample data